# Where is the best place to ask technical C++ questions which verge on opinion-based topics?

Tags: discussion

Where on Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange might I ask questions which are related to C++ coding, but could verge on opinion-based topics, despite still being quite technical? Or is there another place I can do so?

For example, I was taught that C++ code shouldn't use global variables, but I have many real cases where I can't understand where to put the data so that it could be easily accessed and yet not global. Or, for example, when somebody says that interfaces must be always used and data must be hidden, why can't I treat my *[std::vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_(C%2B%2B)#Vector)* member as an interface, rather than data? And what about structures for points in 2D and 3D, why do they need interfaces?

Please don't send me to forums for beginners. I have been using C++ since 1992 and participated in many complex projects. I just want to see if people have found better solutions since then.

What would be the best place to publish such questions?

Comment: The internet is not divided to [SO] and "forums for beginners". There are plenty of communities for experienced developers which allow open ended discussions.

Comment: These topics look fine for Stack Overflow as long as you post it as an actual question and not a forum discussion.

Comment: Questions like these may be on-topic on [softwareengineering.se], see for example https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/396865/c-recursive-descent-parser-global-variable-dilemma, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/441174/what-are-the-considerations-between-a-class-variable-and-a-global-variable, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/392146/how-to-prevent-global-variables-in-a-big-project, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294737/are-file-scope-static-variables-in-c-as-bad-as-extern-global-variables.

Comment: Or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+std%3A%3Avector for various questions related to the use of `std::vector`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, that's exactly what I am asking for. What are those "plenty of communities for experienced developers which allow open ended discussions". I am not born with embedded knowledge about them and googling doesn't help much here. At least, for me. That's why I am asking. Is it bad to ask?

Comment: @Dharman, I see where you coming from but the question about globals, for example, would come to "kill" against "feel free to use" opinion-based discussions with very hard time to find the balance. Interfaces even worse and opinions totally depend on the learning path of the person. So, I am not sure how to shape the questions to make them safe. Will see the links below from Marijn.

Comment: @Marijn, thank you, this helps. Although these questions more technical (how to avoid, how to control) rather than common "Why?" and "When?", they are close. I will read more carefully and give a try for mine one.
Of course, std::vector was an example of "data vs interface". I don't have any questions on std::vector and its usage. My point why getData() interface is must and just std::vector data is evil. And I know everything about encapsulation, changes, even about insulation. My questions are like "is it worth in real project?"

Comment: They could probably find a home at Reddit. For example, [r/coding](https://www.reddit.com/r/coding/) is overrun by (essentially) link spam (most posts seem to violate at least one of [the rules](https://www.reddit.com/r/coding/comments/tzfc78/read_first_rcoding_rules_avoid_moderator_action/)), but they *may* (or may not) very much welcome a post that isn't link spam. The rules explicitly mention *r/learnprogramming* for posting beginner questions.

Comment: "What are those "plenty of communities for experienced developers which allow open ended discussions". I am not born with embedded knowledge about them and googling doesn't help much here." - **Really**? I literally tried putting `c++ forum for experts` into a search engine and got https://isocpp.org/std/forums off the top. There are tons of options out there.

Comment: "My questions are like "is it worth in real project?"" - **If you have to ask, then yes**. If you are actually an expert, you are perfectly well equipped already to try it, see what happens, *recognize the consequences*, and evaluate for yourself. A topic like that doesn't simply verge on opinion-based; it's blatantly opinion-based, and nobody can make the decision for you except by patronizing you.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic on SE sites. Including here. PS This post reflects no research effort.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, thank you for the perfect exemplar. Can you please pinpoint a specific place at [socpp.org/std/forums](socpp.org/std/forums) where these topics could be discussed? As I see from the front page of the site, this is forum for highly technical stuff like proposals for new standard, discussion of very specific technical topics, etc. I am quite sure that for these questions people will again answer like "Focus on real specific tasks and don't waste time on meaningless decorations".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, on your second comment. I see where you coming from, but I have here two goals: (1) To learn if people have found nice solutions for this during these years that I could have missed; (2) I want to have more good arguments when it comes to defend my stand during architect or code reviews.

Comment: @philipxy, I see people already fixed my mistake, so no requests for off-site resources anymore. I see the reason. On the lack of research effort, what visible outcome in question would you like to see? The list of all SO areas sorted by suitability in my opinion? Something else? I just don't know where is better to do this and I ask, what's wrong with it? When you ask for a road in a city, nobody asks you if you walked around last day to find yourself, people just provide information which you could use for forming better questions. This is the effort as I see it. Correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: @PeterMortensen r/coding does not even allow text posts, so there does not even seem to way to ask a question there. I use r/learnprogramming or r/c_programming the most often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some other Stack Exchange sites such as [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) have different criteria for what might be considered a subjective question, and the former will tell you if you have a specific piece of code that you want to ask about improving or has bad practice, which would be closed on Stack Overflow. You could write a working real-world C++ program that uses global variables or exposed data members and post that to Code Review and see what they say.

Questions about language design rationale could be asked on [Programming Language Design or Implementation](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to browse existing recent questions or check their help or Meta pages to get an idea of what is considered on topic.

Alternatively, you could try asking in chat, for example, in [C++ Questions and Answers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116940/c-questions-and-answers). Chat is a less formal environment than the Q&A and may be more accepting of subjective questions.